# NSArray arrayWithObjects: if nil is meant to mark array end, can I do ...nil, nil]?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, null

If nil is meant to mark the end of parameters, then can I use:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil, nil, nil];
```

as the first nil marks array end and two nils after will be ignored?

I got two opposite answers and will try it out.

update:

The reason why I need to do this, is I need to create an UIAlertView, which may have buttons: 'OK' only, or 'Call' and 'Cancel', so either 'OK' or 'Cancel', is the cancel button, whereas 'Call' is other buttons in one case, in other cases, I do not need any other buttons, that's why I need to do this.

Comment: you know, for `UIAlertView` as you say you need it for, you can just add buttons individually using `addButtonWithTitle:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The addition of nil to the end is not intended to add nils to an array, its simply an artifact of how C processes ... variable argument lists.  It has nothing to do with NSArray or NSMutableArray, you cannot store nil in either.

So whether the compiler accepts, nil, nil, nil is actually irrelevant.  The compiler will stop reading at the first nil.  And writing that code in the first place shows a misunderstanding of obj C collections and var arg methods.

Why not use the new literal syntax and just say

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"bla", @"bla", @"bla"];
```

Either way the extra nils matter not in the syntax you provided.

Comment: Yes but actually I am using this for UIAlertView when adding other buttons, so I have either ["Call" "Cancel"] or just ["OK"], so I check: otherButtons: (canMakeCall? "Call" : "OK"), (canMakeCall ? "Cancel" : nil), nil.

Answer (score 12):

When you put `nil` when creating `NSArray`, objects upto that `nil` get added. The `nil` and objects after that are ignored. Just to complete, you [can't add](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDEFAA) `nil` to `NSMutableArray` also (say using `addObject:` method) and doing that will raise exception.

you can put `[NSNull null];` though when creating NSArray.

Comment: We can add [NSNull null] in NSMutableArray also

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exactly, this can be done. The nils after the first one will be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you intentionally add nil to an array? I think you'd better stop a bit and think twice about why do you have to do this. If you are unsure about the size of the array, you can always go with NSMutableArray.

Comment: OP is not, as the other two answers explain, adding `nil` to the array. Neither `NSArray` nor `NSMutableArray` can contain `nil`.