# Objective C NSMutableArray work with nil

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I want to create a `NSMutableArray` to represent a game board that holds grid element (assume I have a *chess* class). In this case, I already know the size of the board so I want to create an array by `initWithCapacity:[size]` and then initialize them as `nil`. During the game, I may insert or remove *chess* object into/from this array based on game. I need to check if some cell is `nil` sometimes.

Clearly `initWithCapacity` only allocate memory, but gives an empty array whose element is not assessable. I think insert `[NSNull null]` one by one is inefficient (I can turn to use 0 to represent `nil` but still not what I want).

Is there any type/structure in Objective C like a C/C++ array for my purpose? Or is it wise to use C/C++ array here? (e.g. `Chess myArray[size]`)

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking here. Are you asking how to use nil with arrays, or how to populate an array with them?

Comment: Read the spec!! You cannot put `nil` values in an NS(Mutable)Array.  If you need to represent "null", use the NSNull singleton object.

Comment: @HotLicks, they already know about NSNull, but (mistakenly) worry that it's inefficient.

Comment: NSNull is quite efficient.  Among other things, you can compare to it directly (`if (somepointer == [NSNull null])`) vs having to use some sort of "equals" method call.

Comment: Yeah, I include in my answer that NSNull is efficient. It's a singleton, so won't be allocating lots of memory unnecessarily.

Comment: @AndyIbanez I'm confused about how to populate an array with `[NSNull null]`. Is there a better way to fill the array with `nil` like C/C++ array when the array is created, instead of enumerating the array (e.g. `for (i=0;i<size;i++) {[myArray addObject:[NSNull null]];}`).

Comment: Offhand, I don't think there's any one-statement way to say "fill the array with 27 copies of this object", or some such.  You gotta write the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **by design** that `NSMutableArray`s and other collections do not permit `nil` and `[NSNull null]` is used as a placeholder for the concept of "nothing" instead.

> I think insert `[NSNull null]` one by one is inefficient

`[NSNull null]` is a singleton, so won't allocate lots of memory unnecessarily and is not inefficient.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/836624/916299) has more information.

---

> Anther efficiency I'm concerning about `[NSNull null]` is when I first create the array, if this array is kind of large (say 100 entries)

100 elements isn't a problem. Your device will be able to iterate 100 elements **very** quickly. Time it if you like.

> is enumeration the only way I can assign a nil to each of these 100 entries? (e.g. `for (i=0;i<size;i++) {[myArray addObject:[NSNull null]];}`

It's the first way I would think of doing it.

---

***"Premature optimisation is the root of all evil"***
<sub>[Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)</sub>

You seem to be concentrating on optimisation too early. You should favour **readability over efficiency** at this point.

When your app seems to slow down, or near the end of a release, profile the application and find out what, if any problems exist. Otherwise you may find yourself spending a day "optimising" a for loop to find that you've saved 0.000001s per update.

Moreover, readable code is easier to:

- debug
- update
- maintain
- share

Micro-optimised code **takes longer** to produce, is prone to **bugs**, difficult to **debug** and **maintain** and often impossible to share as another developer may not know how to interpret your optimisations.

That's not to say "don't optimise", rather concentrate on optimising the biggest problems.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes after the first `nil` nothing after that will be read. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908045/nsarray-arraywithobjects-if-nil-is-meant-to-mark-array-end-can-i-do-nil-ni

Comment: Read the answer to the question you've linked, @NateLee (and James Webster): `nil` is not a member of the collection -- it's only used as a sentinel for the end of the _variadic arguments_ to the _method_. The array does not need a sentinel value; it knows its own length (and [isn't stored contiguously anyways](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html)).

Comment: Comment removed because the offending text was fixed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Anther efficiency I'm concerning about `[NSNull null]` is when I first create the array, if this array is kind of large (say 100 entries), is enumeration the only way I can assign a `nil` to each of these 100 entries? (e.g. `for (i=0;i<size;i++) {[myArray addObject:[NSNull null]];}`)

Comment: @XiZhu, I've edited my answer to respond to the questions in the comment.

Comment: Yeah, we need to cut off premature optimization at it's routes. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"First", @"Second", @"Third"]];
[array addObject:[NSNull null]];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (![obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        // Do something
    }
}];
```