# Is there a Swift one-liner to remove an element from an array if present and append it if not?

Tags: swift, higher-order-functions, set-theory

This is a construct I come across quite a lot. Is there a nice way to one-line it in Swift?

I could just write an extension on Sequence for it, but I feel like there's a "obvious" higher-order-function / set theory technique that is eluding me.

```
if array.contains(element) {
    array.removeObject(object: element)
}
else {
    array.append(element)
}
```

I don't think the solution will even necessarily be *nicer* per se, it's just something I think about every time I have to write this.

Comment: Is there an option to use `Set` instead?

Comment: the simple answer is not using an Array , try to use Set . 
Set doesn't accept duplicates so it won't be added if already exist.

Comment: @PGDev, let's say yes. I think I could colour in a Venn diagram of what I want, but I couldn't figure out how to code it using the options available in Swift's Set.

Comment: @SafoineMoncefAmine, that's not quite what that code is doing. It's swapping the presence of the element in the array.. Removing it if it's present and adding it if not.

Comment: The same in one line:
```array.contains(element) ? array.removeObject(object: element) : array.append(element)```

Comment: @Starsky, my colleague suggested that. She suffixed it with `//Technically one line `

Comment: @Starsky hahaha i was just answering that. Guess I should not anymore.

Comment: `if array.contains(element) { array.removeObject(object: element) } else { array.append(element) }`

Comment: Rather than writing the shortest code try to write the most efficient code  And there is no equivalent to NSArray's `removeObject` in Swift.

Comment: @vadian, rather than writing the "most efficient" code, profile your code occasionally and decide which bits are worth optimising. "Premature optimisation is the route of all evil" after all.

Comment: @vadian: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28174952/916299

Comment: @JamesWebster I generally agree, but there's obvious stuff that you should avoid in almost any case. Your proposed "append if doesn't exist" API would be `O(n)`, and undoubtedly called as part of some loop that's at least `O(n)`. `O(n^2)` explodes pretty fast, at very common real life data sets. People have thousands of songs, contacts, 10s/100s of thousands of files, etc.

Comment: @JamesWebster I know this looks funny and easy, but you actually asked for a one-liner ))))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the part of Set Theory that was eluding me! The result I want is the [Symmetric Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of the two arrays and this *is* included in [Swift's set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/3128856-symmetricdifference):

```
var element = Set([1])
var set = Set([1, 2, 3])

set = set.symmetricDifference(element) //2, 3
set = set.symmetricDifference(element) //1, 2, 3
```

Comment: You don't need to convert the element to a set, you can just write `set = set.symmetricDifference([1])`

Comment: [formSymmetricDifference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/formsymmetricdifference(_:)-22p0m)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Set` instead,

```
var set: Set<Int> = [1, 2, 4]
if !set.insert(4).inserted {
    set.remove(4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the great answer by. James Webster. We can enhance for reusability.

```swift
extension Set {
    /// Inserts given element if it doesn't exist in the set or removes it.
    ///
    mutating func withSymmetricDifference(_ element: Element) {
        self = symmetricDifference([element])
    }
}
```

Usage

```swift
var set = Set([1, 2, 3])
set.withSymmetricDifference(1) // [1, 2, 3]
set.withSymmetricDifference(1) // [2, 3]
```