# Error: [__NSArrayM addObject:], NIL object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I receive the following error: `[__NSArrayM addObject:]`, NIL object.  but not crash ,I want to know why display this remind.
here is my code

```
NSMutableArray *picturesCounts = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *bigUrlArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *pitcturesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger i = 1;
for (TNHotelPictures *picture in pictures) {
    NSString *pictureCounts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)picture.images.count];
    [picturesCounts addObject:pictureCounts];
    [pitcturesArray addObject:picture.images];

    for (TNHotelDetailPhotoImages *photoImage in picture.images) {
        [bigUrlArray addObject:photoImage.bigUrl];
    }
    i++;
}
NSInteger imageInAllIndex = imageIndex;
NSMutableArray *imagesCount = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger m = 0; m<i; m++) {
    imagesCount = pitcturesArray[(typeIndex-(m+1))] ;
    imageInAllIndex += imagesCount.count;
}

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *url in bigUrlArray)
    {
        if (![url isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
                return;
        }
    TNHotelPhoto *photo = [[TNHotelPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [array addObject:photo];
    }

TNHotelPhotoSource *source = [[TNHotelPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:array];
TNHotelDetailPhotoBrowserViewController *browserVC = [[TNHotelDetailPhotoBrowserViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source WithImageIndex:imageInAllIndex>=0?imageInAllIndex:0 andImageArray:pictures andTypeIndex:typeIndex];

[UIManager showViewController:browserVC];
```

}

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908045/nsarray-arraywithobjects-if-nil-is-meant-to-mark-array-end-can-i-do-nil-ni

Comment: Your code does some very strange things.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the object has been initialized and holding a reference in memory. Its not a `NIL`.

Answer (score 0):

See your code:

```
for (TNHotelPictures *picture in pictures) {
    NSString *pictureCounts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)picture.images.count];
    [picturesCounts addObject:pictureCounts];
    [pitcturesArray addObject:picture.images];

    for (TNHotelDetailPhotoImages *photoImage in picture.images) {
        [bigUrlArray addObject:photoImage.bigUrl];
    }
    i++;
    }
```

I think you should check the `picture` whether its properties `pictureCounts`,`images`,`bigUrl` are not nil.

Comment: thank you very much, photoImage.bigUrl should  judge wherher is nil，because